# jQuery Bootstrap isn't functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry if this has been answered before, please link me if so, I couldn't find anything..

Basically, my jQuery worked fine on Bootstrap, up to the point I made a favicon. Now I think either my script / head tag alignment is off, so I tried to fix that for the past hour, but nothing is working.

Also putting the script at the end of the body, like normal, doesn't work. Not sure what I've done wrong here.

```
    <html lang="en"><head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title></title>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:400,300,700,900,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

 <!-- snip html -->

    <!-- jQuery Version -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




</body></html>
```

I know it's in there twice now, but neither works. What's wrong? :(

Edit: Dropdown doesn't work, this is the HTML for the dropdown:

```
        <!-- Navigation -->
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo/logo.png" class="img-responsive img-icon" /></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-default">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

I changed some CSS for buttons, is that the problem?

```
/* Navbar Colours - Fixing Dropdown */

.nav > li a {
    color: #e97117;
}

.nav > li a:hover, a:focus {
    color: #e97117;
}

/* Navbar link Colours */

.navbar-default a:hover, a:focus {
    color: #e97117 !important;
}

/* Button Colour */

.btn {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}

.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus {
    color: #e97117;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #e97117;
}

.btn-secondary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #fff;
}

.btn-secondary:hover,
.btn-secondary:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #e97117;
    border-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting that is indicating jQuery is no longer working?

Comment: There is no error, not even when I inspect element my page, but my drowndown isn't working in Bootstrap

Comment: It would help to include the code for your dropdown that isn't working. It's possible the issue is there

Comment: Yup just did, thanks.

Comment: Also added the CSS, which I doubt is a problem, but please tell me if it is

Comment: you definitely don't want to load bootstrap and jquery twice :-)

Comment: I'm not trying to, I've tried them seperately, I've tried them together, I've tried any combination you can think of and nothing works.

Comment: Do you have jquery included in your directory?

Comment: I have two versions of jQuery in my js folder, neither of them work.

Comment: Are you testing on your "homepage"... the paths to your assets are relative and if you are not on the "homepage" they will not be found.  Do you see any 404 errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the line defining the collapse button:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
```

Notice how it has `data-target`. That refers to what element to look for to collapse. If you look at the [example on the Bootstrap site](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) you'll notice that the main navbar content div has that ID (which your HTML is missing):

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```

Comment: Gonna try this now, do I add the ID to the button ID line or the div?

Comment: @AnneKok You should add the id to the div. Check out the example given with Bootstrap

Comment: I did it, but it does not help.

Comment: @AnneKok Did you follow the advice of imvain2 and include `bootstrap.min.js` after jquery?

Comment: I did everything... I really dont get it :(

Comment: @AnneKok I'm sorry but I don't know what's going wrong with your code. It works for me: http://codepen.io/jdelaney/pen/OXyMbQ

Comment: @J Delaney it just doesnt work, but it works in the snippets fine. I think I wreckt the code someway or the other and my tunnel vision is so bad I cant figure it out. Can someone personally help me? I dont feel like pasting the whole code here

Comment: I'm making a website for one of my companies partners so I'd appreciate it being discreet without posting it everywhere on the web thats why I dont wanna post it

Comment: @AnneKok You can find my Twitter handle on my profile. Feel free to send me a direct message there

Comment: @J Delaney apparently I cant send messages to ppl that dont follow me.

Comment: @J Delaney I'm sending you a mail on gmail.

Answer (score 3):

As @jdelaney indicated, you are missing a key ID.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-default" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```

Also, in your code example the path to your js and css is "page relative" rather than "site relative" or "fully qualified".  So, if you are testing on a page that is not your "homepage" it is quite possible that you are not loading those assets at all.  Do you happen to see 404 errors at all in the console?

Anyways, this example seems to work for me with the @jdelaney suggested edit.

```css
.nav > li a {
    color: #e97117;
}

.nav > li a:hover, a:focus {
    color: #e97117;
}

/* Navbar link Colours */

.navbar-default a:hover, a:focus {
    color: #e97117 !important;
}

/* Button Colour */

.btn {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}

.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus {
    color: #e97117;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #e97117;
}

.btn-secondary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #fff;
}

.btn-secondary:hover,
.btn-secondary:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #e97117;
    border-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="img/logo/logo.png" class="img-responsive img-icon" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-default" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Did I break the internet?

Comment: Are you saying that when you run this code snippet, the hamburger menu does not work?  I ask because it does for me.

Comment: It works in the snippet fine, but not on my website I'm creating.

Comment: @AnneKok it works for me. What's not working for you?

Comment: @essaji it works fine for me in the snippet, but on my website it does not :(

Comment: @AnneKok try copy pasting the entire code from here. I am sure there must be some minor mistake in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en"><head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title></title>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:400,300,700,900,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
 
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
          </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-default">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>



</body></html>
```

First thing I would try is in the head:

change

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @AnneKok  it may not work but imvain2 is entirely right that you should be sure to include the Bootstrap JavaScript library after jQuery

Comment: Oh yeh I'm aware of that.

Comment: It seems to work.  When you say it does not work, what do you mean?

Comment: Dropdown doesn't expand

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem arises when you include JQuery two times. I can see in your code you're referencing `<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>` at the two places. Remove the one in the `head` tag & try again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example html and css code and I only changed the inclusion of jquery and bootstrap (removed the jquery from  section and included jquery and bootstrap from cdn) and as you can see it works without any problems.

Double check if your jquery and bootstrap are included correctly (path to the files / version conflicts?).

```css
    /* Navbar Colours - Fixing Dropdown */

    .nav > li a {
        color: #e97117;
    }

    .nav > li a:hover,
    a:focus {
        color: #e97117;
    }


    /* Navbar link Colours */

    .navbar-default a:hover,
    a:focus {
        color: #e97117 !important;
    }


    /* Button Colour */

    .btn {
        color: #fff;
        font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
    }

    .btn-default:hover,
    .btn-default:focus {
        color: #e97117;
        background-color: transparent;
        border-color: #e97117;
    }

    .btn-secondary {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: transparent;
        border-color: #fff;
    }

    .btn-secondary:hover,
    .btn-secondary:focus {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #e97117;
        border-color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title></title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link  href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:400,300,700,900,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
    <body>

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo/logo.png" class="img-responsive img-icon" /></a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-default">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>

        <!-- jQuery Version -->
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>
```

Comment: thats not clear to my why. did you copy&past to your local installation or does the code also not work if you click to "Run code snippet" and then click to "Full page"?

Comment: The  code works fine on the snippet, but does not if I copy and paste it into my own code.

Comment: Do you have any error messages in your browser's console? If you try the above code in a local file replace all // inlcudes to https:// and it should work.

Comment: Do you try it in a plain html file or do you have any CMS where you included the code? If you use a CMS please post the not working html from your generated page source.

Comment: No CMS, just running it locally. There are 0 errors in the console. I've checked them a thousand times, and it never gives me an error.

Comment: Hmm strange... what browser do you use (and what version)? Maybee a firewall blocking your includes?

Comment: Firewall is not blocking anything. My firewall settings are fine. I am testing it in chrome, firefox, IE and all give the same problem. No errors in console, yet, it doesn't work.

Comment: I've no other ideas where the problem is. Sorry :(

Comment: It's been fixed! It was a problem in my CSS! But thank you for trying, I really appreciate it !

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the CSS.

I had added an overflow:hidden function which I read over because I was tunnel visioned onto jQuery.

J Delaney helped me find it and it's all fixed now.

Thanks everyone that tried to help me! You couldn't possibly have known without the whole code, but I still really appreciate your help!